# Problema com Ngnix no OS X Mavericks

Tags: nginx

nginx:

> [alert] could not open error log file: open()
>   "/usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
>   2014/02/05 14:02:43 [emerg] 20175#0: open()
>   "/Users/username/code/product/log/nginx_access.log" failed (2: No such
>   file or directory)

Comment: Pode descrever o problema?

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow, para postar uma Pergunta, você tem que ter uma pergunta. No seu caso você apenas postou um Erro, e disse que foi no `nginx` porém não sabemos o que você está tentando fazer, não temos acesso ao seu código, muito menos sabemos como proceder para te ajudar, por isso complemente sua pergunta com uma Pergunta Real.

Answer (score 1):

Rode os comandos

> sudo mkdir -p /Users/username/code/product/log/
>
> sudo touch /Users/username/code/product/log/nginx_access.log
>
> sudo chmod 777 /Users/username/code/product/log/nginx_access.log

e restarte o nginx

Comment: sudo touch /Users/nego/code/product/log/nginx_access.log                                                   1 ↵
touch: /Users/nego/code/product/log/nginx_access.log: No such file or directory

Comment: atualizei com um comando a mais

Comment: sudo chmod 777 nginx_access.log

 ls
nginx_access.log
nginx
nginx: [emerg] open() "/Users/username/code/product/log/nginx_error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem de erro está dizendo duas coisas:

1ª - que o o usuário rodando o NginX **não tem permissões de acesso** ao *arquivo de log de erro*: `/usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log`

2ª - que o **diretório** do *arquivo de log de acessos* **não existe**:
`/Users/username/code/product/log`

---

Eu resolveria o caso da seguinte maneira:

1º - verificando qual usuário está rodando o NginX; é só conferir o arquivo de configuração, através do comando:

`sudo cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep user`

2º - alterando as configurações de arquivo de log do NginX para arquivos que possam ser acessados pelo respectivo usuário (em diretórios que existam, é claro)... execute os comandos a seguir para verificar em quais arquivos estão as configurações:

```
cd /etc/nginx
sudo grep -R log *
```

3º - edite os arquivos (`sudo pico nginx.conf` ou similar) e reinicie (`sudo service nginx restart`)

---

Observação: os comandos acima servem para um Linux Ubuntu moderno; se o seu sistema for outro, aplicar as devidas adaptações